# Как сохранить куки?

Tags: cookie, jsoup, java

Всем привет!

Не могу сохранить для дальнейшего использования куки с сайта работа66.ру.

Вот, собственно, написанный код:

```
Response res = Jsoup
                .connect("http://www.rabota66.ru/login")
                .data("LoginForm[login]", login, "LoginForm[password]", password)
                .method(Method.POST)
                .execute();
Map<String, String> loginCookies = res.cookies();
```

Comment: Уточните, вы не можете сохранить `Map<Strinbg, String>` куда бы то ни было? Или `res.cookies()` не дает ожидаемого результата? В приведенном коде по виду ошибок нет.

Comment: res.cookies() выдает мне только те куки, которые я могу получить с сайта без авторизации.

Comment: @ath01, там еще два параметра должны передаваться. Т.е. логин у вас, видимо, не проходит. Посмотрите в браузере в firebug'е на закладке Network, какие данные передаются, и попытайтесь добиться соответствия в jsoup.